# Responsive grid, how to add margin between columns?

Tags: responsive-design, grid, margin

I'm watching course about html & css and use modified responsive grid from here:
http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

If browser width decreases, divs go to new lines and finally are shown in one column. It works, but

cannot add horizontal spacing between elements:

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0g0chrh/1/)

**index.html**

```
 <!-- FIRST ROW -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-2 box">
        <h3>first-row span-1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-2 box">
        <h3>first-row span-2</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND ROW -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <h3>second-row span-1</h3>
        <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
            work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <h3>second-row span-2</h3>
        <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
            work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <h3>second-row span-3</h3>
        <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
            work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <h3>second-row span-4</h3>
        <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
            work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Media.css**

```
/* small phones to small tyablets 481 to 767 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span-1-of-2 { width: 98%; padding-right: 1%;}
    .span-1-of-4, .span-2-of-4, .span-3-of-4, .span-4-of-4 { width: 45%; }
} 

/* small phones 0 to 480 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%; }
    .span-1-of-4, .span-2-of-4, .span-3-of-4, .span-4-of-4 { width: 100%; }
}
```

**styles.css**

```
/* -------- REUSABLE COMPONENETS -------- */
* {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ' ';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* row class from grid css */
.row {               
    width: 1140px;  
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

section {
    padding: 80px 0;
} 

 /* class to modify out-of-the-box grid classes (like 'span-1-of-4') */
.box {             

    background-color: #1ba1e2;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

**grid.css**

```
/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */

.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */


.span-2-of-2 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-2-of-2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */


.span-3-of-3 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span-2-of-3 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-3-of-3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/*  GRID OF FOUR   ============================================================================= */


.span-4-of-4 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span-3-of-4 {
    width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-2-of-4 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-1-of-4 {
    width: 23.8%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-4-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-4 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF FIVE   ============================================================================= */


.span-5-of-5 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-4-of-5 {
    width: 79.68%; 
}

.span-3-of-5 {
    width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-2-of-5 {
    width: 39.04%;
}

.span-1-of-5 {
    width: 18.72%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-5-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-5 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF SIX   ============================================================================= */


.span-6-of-6 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-5-of-6 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span-4-of-6 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span-3-of-6 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

.span-2-of-6 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span-1-of-6 {
    width: 15.33%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-6-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-6 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}



/*  GRID OF SEVEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-7-of-7 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-6-of-7 {
    width: 85.48%;
}

.span-5-of-7 {
    width: 70.97%;
}

.span-4-of-7 {
    width: 56.45%;
}

.span-3-of-7 {
    width: 41.94%;
}

.span-2-of-7 {
    width: 27.42%;
}

.span-1-of-7 {
    width: 12.91%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-7-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-7 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF EIGHT   ============================================================================= */


.span-8-of-8 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-7-of-8 {
    width: 87.3%; 
}

.span-6-of-8 {
    width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-5-of-8 {
    width: 61.9%; 
}

.span-4-of-8 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-3-of-8 {
    width: 36.5%;
}

.span-2-of-8 {
    width: 23.8%; 
}

.span-1-of-8 {
    width: 11.1%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-8-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-8 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF NINE   ============================================================================= */


.span-9-of-9 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-8-of-9 {
    width: 88.71%;
}

.span-7-of-9 {
    width: 77.42%; 
}

.span-6-of-9 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-5-of-9 {
    width: 54.84%; 
}

.span-4-of-9 {
    width: 43.55%; 
}

.span-3-of-9 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span-2-of-9 {
    width: 20.97%; 
}

.span-1-of-9 {
    width: 9.68%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-9-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-9 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-10-of-10 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-9-of-10 {
    width: 89.84%;
}

.span-8-of-10 {
    width: 79.68%;
}

.span-7-of-10 {
    width: 69.52%; 
}

.span-6-of-10 {
    width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-5-of-10 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-4-of-10 {
    width: 39.04%; 
}

.span-3-of-10 {
    width: 28.88%;
}

.span-2-of-10 {
    width: 18.72%; 
}

.span-1-of-10 {
    width: 8.56%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-10-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-10 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF ELEVEN   ============================================================================= */

.span-11-of-11 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-10-of-11 {
    width: 90.76%;
}

.span-9-of-11 {
    width: 81.52%;
}

.span-8-of-11 {
    width: 72.29%;
}

.span-7-of-11 {
    width: 63.05%; 
}

.span-6-of-11 {
    width: 53.81%; 
}

.span-5-of-11 {
    width: 44.58%; 
}

.span-4-of-11 {
    width: 35.34%; 
}

.span-3-of-11 {
    width: 26.1%;
}

.span-2-of-11 {
    width: 16.87%; 
}

.span-1-of-11 {
    width: 7.63%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-11-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-10-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-11 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}


/*  GRID OF TWELVE   ============================================================================= */

.span-12-of-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-11-of-12 {
    width: 91.53%;
}

.span-10-of-12 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span-9-of-12 {
    width: 74.6%;
}

.span-8-of-12 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span-7-of-12 {
    width: 57.66%; 
}

.span-6-of-12 {
    width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-5-of-12 {
    width: 40.73%; 
}

.span-4-of-12 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}

.span-3-of-12 {
    width: 23.8%;
}

.span-2-of-12 {
    width: 15.33%; 
}

.span-1-of-12 {
    width: 6.86%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span-12-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-11-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-10-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-9-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-8-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-7-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-6-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-5-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-4-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-3-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-2-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span-1-of-12 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

I'll attach folder with example, which could be opened in HTML Editor
https://mega.nz/#!fh0zSLQR!sNWr7joNedcOPfmEb9BwCAZdTncizAfm9EsQ7ITh8Zk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in your custom grid css.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t0g0chrh/3/

```css
/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */

.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
 }
}


/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */


.span-2-of-2 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-2-of-2 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-2 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF THREE   ============================================================================= */

 
.span-3-of-3 {
 width: 100%; 
}

.span-2-of-3 {
 width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-1-of-3 {
 width: 32.26%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-3-of-3 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-3 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-3 {
  width: 100%;
 }
}

/*  GRID OF FOUR   ============================================================================= */

 
.span-4-of-4 {
 width: 100%; 
}

.span-3-of-4 {
 width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-2-of-4 {
 width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-1-of-4 {
 width: 23.8%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-4-of-4 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-4 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-4 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-4 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF FIVE   ============================================================================= */

 
.span-5-of-5 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-4-of-5 {
   width: 79.68%; 
}

.span-3-of-5 {
   width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-2-of-5 {
   width: 39.04%;
}

.span-1-of-5 {
   width: 18.72%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-5-of-5 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-5 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-5 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-5 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-5 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF SIX   ============================================================================= */


.span-6-of-6 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-5-of-6 {
   width: 83.06%;
}

.span-4-of-6 {
   width: 66.13%;
}

.span-3-of-6 {
   width: 49.2%;
}

.span-2-of-6 {
   width: 32.26%;
}

.span-1-of-6 {
   width: 15.33%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-6-of-6 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-5-of-6 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-6 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-6 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-6 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-6 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}



/*  GRID OF SEVEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-7-of-7 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-6-of-7 {
 width: 85.48%;
}

.span-5-of-7 {
   width: 70.97%;
}

.span-4-of-7 {
   width: 56.45%;
}

.span-3-of-7 {
   width: 41.94%;
}

.span-2-of-7 {
   width: 27.42%;
}

.span-1-of-7 {
   width: 12.91%;
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-7-of-7 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-6-of-7 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-5-of-7 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-7 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-7 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-7 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-7 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF EIGHT   ============================================================================= */

 
.span-8-of-8 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-7-of-8 {
 width: 87.3%; 
}

.span-6-of-8 {
 width: 74.6%; 
}

.span-5-of-8 {
 width: 61.9%; 
}

.span-4-of-8 {
 width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-3-of-8 {
 width: 36.5%;
}

.span-2-of-8 {
 width: 23.8%; 
}

.span-1-of-8 {
 width: 11.1%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-8-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-7-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-6-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-5-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-8 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF NINE   ============================================================================= */


.span-9-of-9 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-8-of-9 {
 width: 88.71%;
}

.span-7-of-9 {
 width: 77.42%; 
}

.span-6-of-9 {
 width: 66.13%; 
}

.span-5-of-9 {
 width: 54.84%; 
}

.span-4-of-9 {
 width: 43.55%; 
}

.span-3-of-9 {
 width: 32.26%;
}

.span-2-of-9 {
 width: 20.97%; 
}

.span-1-of-9 {
 width: 9.68%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-9-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-8-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-7-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-6-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-5-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-9 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF TEN   ============================================================================= */


.span-10-of-10 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-9-of-10 {
 width: 89.84%;
}

.span-8-of-10 {
 width: 79.68%;
}

.span-7-of-10 {
 width: 69.52%; 
}

.span-6-of-10 {
 width: 59.36%; 
}

.span-5-of-10 {
 width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-4-of-10 {
 width: 39.04%; 
}

.span-3-of-10 {
 width: 28.88%;
}

.span-2-of-10 {
 width: 18.72%; 
}

.span-1-of-10 {
 width: 8.56%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-10-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-9-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-8-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-7-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-6-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-5-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-10 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF ELEVEN   ============================================================================= */

.span-11-of-11 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-10-of-11 {
 width: 90.76%;
}

.span-9-of-11 {
 width: 81.52%;
}

.span-8-of-11 {
 width: 72.29%;
}

.span-7-of-11 {
 width: 63.05%; 
}

.span-6-of-11 {
 width: 53.81%; 
}

.span-5-of-11 {
 width: 44.58%; 
}

.span-4-of-11 {
 width: 35.34%; 
}

.span-3-of-11 {
 width: 26.1%;
}

.span-2-of-11 {
 width: 16.87%; 
}

.span-1-of-11 {
 width: 7.63%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-11-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-10-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-9-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-8-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-7-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-6-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-5-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-11 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}


/*  GRID OF TWELVE   ============================================================================= */

.span-12-of-12 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-11-of-12 {
 width: 91.53%;
}

.span-10-of-12 {
 width: 83.06%;
}

.span-9-of-12 {
 width: 74.6%;
}

.span-8-of-12 {
 width: 66.13%;
}

.span-7-of-12 {
 width: 57.66%; 
}

.span-6-of-12 {
 width: 49.2%; 
}

.span-5-of-12 {
 width: 40.73%; 
}

.span-4-of-12 {
 width: 32.26%; 
}

.span-3-of-12 {
 width: 23.8%;
}

.span-2-of-12 {
 width: 15.33%; 
}

.span-1-of-12 {
 width: 6.86%; 
}


/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-12-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-11-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-10-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-9-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-8-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-7-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-6-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-5-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-4-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-12 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}



/* MEDIA.CSS*/

/* small phones to small tyablets 481 to 767 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span-1-of-2 { width: 98%; padding-right: 1%;}
    .span-1-of-4, .span-2-of-4, .span-3-of-4, .span-4-of-4 { width: 48%; }
    .span-1-of-4:nth-child(2n) {
      margin-left: 2%;
    }
} 

/* small phones 0 to 480 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 1% 1% 0%; }
   .span-1-of-2 { width: 100%; padding-right: 1%;}
    .span-1-of-4, .span-2-of-4, .span-3-of-4, .span-4-of-4 { width: 100%; }
    .span-1-of-4:nth-child(2n) {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
} 


/* STYLE.CSS */

/* -------- REUSABLE COMPONENETS -------- */
* {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ' ';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* row class from grid css */
.row {               
    width: 1140px;  
 margin: 0 auto; 
}

section {
    padding: 80px 0;
} 

 /* class to modify out-of-the-box grid classes (like 'span-1-of-4') */
.box {             
 
 background-color: #1ba1e2;
 border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- FIRST ROW -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-2 box">
            <h3>first-row span-1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-2 box">
            <h3>first-row span-2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SECOND ROW -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
            <h3>second-row span-1</h3>
            <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
                work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
            <h3>second-row span-2</h3>
            <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
                work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
            <h3>second-row span-3</h3>
            <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
                work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
            <h3>second-row span-4</h3>
            <p>You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We
                work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow! You added    .span-1-of-2 { width: 100%; padding-right: 1%;}
    and
    .span-1-of-4:nth-child(2n) {
      margin-left: 0;
    } - Thank Youi very much! :) Now works like a charm! :-)